# Is there a way to construct the domain hierarchy of a dataset?

Tags: regression, decision-trees

Could regression trees help defining the domain value hierarchies for the target variable: for example if we perform a DT regression task over a target variable, could we easily derive the hiearchy for that variable?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a domain hierarchy. Could you give an example of a "problem" and what a potential output would be?